c# Download SSRS report using reporting services api is showing as "US ASCII" encoding but I want UTF-8-BOM
Just struggling to find the right c# code to download a ssrs report that has a special character in it, when I see the report online I can see it has a single quote character that is actually not ' but ’. My code rs.Render(..., out encoding, ...) has an out encoding parameter that has a value of "US ASCII" if that matters my code attempts to save the byte stream returned using File.WriteAllBytes(fname, reportBytes);
I have also tried saving as UTF-8-BOM to see if it makes any difference:
var encoding = Encoding.UFT8;
using (var fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(fs, encoding))
    {
        bw.Write(encoding.GetPreamble());
        bw.Write(reportBytes);
    }
}

But whatever I try the file is saved with a question mark ? instead, if you can advise if either my code is wrong and what to change it to or is it possibly the ssrs extenstion save format that is incorrect, it is a custom one for PIPE delimiter and has an DeviceInfo encoding of ASCII.

You have reportBytes. No amount of faffing around with Encoding at this stage is going to change the text in those bytes from being encoded with ASCII to UTF8. You'll need to show us relevant code (i.e. relating to generating the report).

Maybe you could try a modified version of this?

yeah I think u are dead on, it must be the ASCII encoding setting on the server as I just discovered it downloads as I want it to be using CSV format. So I can blame the operator who set up the custom formatting!!

I think read a post the default is UFT-8 so I will try that first. Maybe deleting the encoding altogether would also work.
Failing that try what @ProgrammingLlama suggested

Yes it is working now that I have removed the encoding setting - hooray!
